# Tkinter / ttk on Mac OS X Proper System Background Color (canvas)

Tags: python, macos, canvas, tkinter, ttk

I would like to set the canvas background color to the same default system color as the frame above.

How can I determine the correct background color as used by other widgets in Tkinter/ttk on Mac OS X? I could use a fixed value but would prefer another way. Not sure if ttk is the way to go on OS X at all.

This example tries to get the background color from a frame and sets it to a canvas but it is a different color than the frame (white instead of light grey).

```
from Tkinter import *
from ttk import *

app = Tk()
s = Style()

t = Frame(app)
t.pack()

b1 = Button(t, text="y no right background color")
b1.pack()

b2= Button(t, text="y")
b2.pack()

#bg = "green"
#bg = "#eaeaea"
bg = s.lookup("TButton", "background")
print bg

s.configure('TFrame', background=bg)
c = Canvas(app, background=bg)
c.pack()

mainloop()
```

Comment: Sugegstion: have a look at this method if you want to layout all widgets at once: `tk_setPalette`

Comment: This does not seem to be meant to be used with ttk. I tested it nonetheless but it does not change the frame background color.